# Phonegap 1.3 captureImage to Photo Library and display image in HTML/App interface

Tags: ios, cordova, image-capture

I have been using the following code to grab a photo and display it in html works great.

```
function takePicture() {

navigator.camera.getPicture(
    function(uri) {
        var img = document.getElementById('camera_image1');
        img.style.visibility = "visible";
        img.style.display = "block";
        img.src = uri;
        document.getElementById('camera_status').innerHTML = "Success";

    },

    { quality: 50, allowEdit: true, destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI});
   };
```

html later

```
 <img style="width:144px;height:144px;" id="camera_image1" src="nophoto.jpg"/>
```

However I would like to save the image to the users Library at the same time, any pointer much appreciated.

I have tried using captureImage but this gives me less options like editing and did not place image inline in html.

Thanks again

PhoneGap 1.3

Answer (score 1):

With Phonegap 2.2 you can save the image to the local device.

add `"saveToPhotoAlbum : true"` to the `cameraOptions`

```
function takePicture() {

navigator.camera.getPicture(
    function(uri) {
        var img = document.getElementById('camera_image1');
        img.style.visibility = "visible";
        img.style.display = "block";
        img.src = uri;
        document.getElementById('camera_status').innerHTML = "Success";

    }, { 
       quality: 50, 
       allowEdit: true, 
       destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
       saveToPhotoAlbum : true
    });

};
```

Answer (score 0):

you'll have to change the phonegap code a bit. it wont save the image in the implementation thats there currently.
tell me if you are working on phonegap android. may be able to help u with that.

Comment: I am using Phonegap:build so cross platform :(